# How to nest data with ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

After running through ALL the examples, I guess my only choice is doing a custom template based somewhat on this [example](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/hierarchy.html) , although not every row will have children.

Does anyone have any recommendations for this kind of implementation?

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start using columnDefs in grid options and specify a cell template. Below is an example i did a while ago.

```
$scope.gridOptionsForLocationList = {
        data: yourdata,
        selectedItems: $scope.selectedLocations,
        showFilter: false,
        showColumnMenu: false,
        headerRowHeight: 0,
        enableRowSelection: false,
        columnDefs: [
            {field:'cityId', displayName:'#', width: 0},
            {field:'suburbId', displayName:'#', width: 0},
            {field:'cityName', displayName:'City'},
            {field:'suburbName', displayName:'Suburban'},
            { field: '',cellClass:'right' , cellTemplate: '<button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-mini" ng-click="deleteLocations(row)">click</button>' }]
};
```

In cell template, write an html that wraps the text on a second line and give an indent for a child div. Maybe that may help your case.